# How to enable file size limit in Quarkus access log

Tags: quarkus

I'm using Quarkus for my application and have configured the access log to be written to a file. However, I currently don't have any file size limit set for the access log, and it keeps growing indefinitely. I would like to enable a file size limit to ensure the log file doesn't become too large.

I've already checked the Quarkus documentation and various configuration options, but couldn't find a specific property or configuration to set the file size limit for the access log.

Comment: It seems we don't provide that configuration option. Can you please open an issue in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues asking for that feature?

Comment: GitHub Issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34084